# StatusBar orientation wrong when receiving orientation changed notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uideviceorientation

I have 2 view controller registered to receive a Device orientation changed notification.  `

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
>   selector:@selector(repositionView)
>   name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

`

In the reposition view method I have :

```
   UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        NSLog(@"view (%@) will set orientation landscape",self);
// do smt
    } else {
          NSLog(@"view (%@) will set orientation portrait",self);
//do smt else 
    }
```

They are both in memory when the orientation changes

```
2013-11-27 17:37:54.277 App[13782:70b] view (<ViewController: 0xbf09950>) will set orientation landscape
2013-11-27 17:37:54.286 App[13782:70b] view (<ViewController: 0xc095e40>) will set orientation portrait
2013-11-27 17:38:17.318 App[13782:70b] view (<ViewController: 0xbf09950>) will set orientation portrait
2013-11-27 17:38:20.123 App[13782:70b] view (<ViewController: 0xc095e40>) will set orientation landscape
```

Only one receives the correct orientation. 
Why is this ? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification** instead of UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(repositionView:) name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:nil];


-(void)repositionView:(NSNotification *)notification
{
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey: UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey] integerValue];

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        NSLog(@"view (%@) will set orientation landscape",self);
// do smt
    } else {
          NSLog(@"view (%@) will set orientation portrait",self);
//do smt else 
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems to work but now i have aprox 6 calls to the method. 3/ view controller. Why?

Comment: repositionView method will be called  when the orientation of the app’s user interface changes.

Comment: No, one rotation will send 3 notification to all viewCOntrollers

Comment: if your are adding observer in each view controller. it will be called 3 times means once in all view controller. Whenever change in the orientation in application this method is called.

Comment: No, on the logs it shows 6 notifications for 2 viewControllers ... 3/ controller